# Prove that if $x+y \geq 2$, where x and y are real numbers, then, x $\geq 1 \vee y \geq 1$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I understand that one can prove this by using contraposition. The point that got me unsatisfied with this solution is that I have no idea about why one wouldn't use the Direct Proof Method when proving this? If possible, could you please use the direct proof method for the solution of this question and well, if impossible, explain the reason behind the uselesness of the direct proof method in this example?

Comment: By "direct proof", do you mean a proof that does not use proof by contradiction? if so, then I think you will find such a proof for this proposition quite tricky.

Answer (score 2):

We have $x-1+y-1\geq0$.

Let $y-1<0$.

Thus, $x-1\geq-(y-1)>0$, which gives $x-1\geq0,$ which we need.

But, $y-1\geq0$ gives, which we need again.

Comment: I couldn't get it quite well. First: Why we let $y - 1 < 0$. Second: Is not $x - 1 \geq 0$ a false statement, since $-(y - 1) > 0$ and so $x - 1$ is? Instead we would write it down like this: $x - 1 > 0$. Third, I need some deeper explanation of the last part which says, $y - 1 \geq 0$. Thanks.

Comment: I suspect the OP wants an intuitionistically acceptable proof, i.e., one that doesn't use the law of the excluded middle. I don't think disguising $\lnot y - 1 \ge 0$ as $y - 1 < 0$ is going to help.

Comment: @Çağan Kuyucu There are two cases only: 1) $y-1<0$; 2) $y-1\geq0$. In all these cases our statement is proven. Also, if $x-1>0$ then $x-1\geq0$.